Container get detached after restating the vm
In Azure, I mounted the container to my Ubuntu VM following the document: How to mount an Azure Blob Storage container on Linux with BlobFuse2.
I'm able to attach the container, but after the VM is restarted, that mount point gets detached and I have to run blobfuse2 mount to mount it. I added an entry in fstab, but I'm still facing the same issue. The following is my fstab file:
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
UUID=90dbb72d-9869-4713-b6f0-9618fa7b481b       /        ext4   discard,commit=30,errors=remount-ro     0 1
LABEL=BOOT      /boot   ext4    defaults,discard        0 2
UUID=9C78-5597  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0 1
/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.after=cloud-init.service,_netdev,comment=cloudconfig  0       2
blobfuse2#graphlit-ingestion /mnt/graphlit-ingestion fuse rw,config=/home/azureuser/blobfuse2-config/config.yaml,allow_other 0 0


I think you may have to contact Microsoft / Azure for  assistance with their blobfuse2 integrations. If that is not able to mount automatically it may be a known issue on Microsoft's infrastructure.  Note that MS regularly has issues in their documentation where they don't mention stuff like this, so it's prudent to reach out to their support in this case.
